# Calling from twilio sub account using <dial>

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I am using voice-quickstart-ios but i am facing some problems here.
I need to know a few things.

1. How can I make call from sub account without using REST API rather [TwiML <dial>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial)?
2. If point 1 is not possible then how can i make call without changing leg of the call or if i had to change the leg then how can i retrieve it in voice-quickstart-ios SDK?
3. How can i record a call with leg CallSid using REST API?(if i can retrieve leg of the call)
4. Does twilio cloud have scheduler? (eg: firebase pubsub)?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

Q: How can I make call from sub account without using REST API rather TwiML ?

A: You cannot initiate a call using Twilio Markup Language (TwiML), only manage an existing call. You will need to use the REST API ([Calls Resource](https://www.google.com/search?q=Twilio%20Calls%20Resource)) to initiate a call.

Q: If point 1 is not possible then how can i make call without changing leg of the call or if i had to change the leg then how can i retrieve it in voice-quickstart-ios SDK?

A: I don't understand this question. Can you provide more details on what you mean? Two call legs are involved when connecting  parties, sometimes referred to as the "parent" leg (the main leg) and the "child" leg, the leg that is kicked off by some action of the parent. Your iOS SDK leg would be the parent leg, if making an outbound call toward Twilio  and would use TwiML to create the child leg.

How can i record a call with leg CallSid using REST API?(if i can retrieve leg of the call)

A: Using the REST API [Recording Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording)e.

Q: Does Twilio cloud have scheduler? (eg: firebase pubsub)?

A: Not at this time.

Comment: i did what your documentation asked for, previously i was able to record call from my master account using that REST API you mentioned,
but when i am trying to record a call from sub account it fails. i think this is because of using parent call sid when recording that call but my makeCall endpoint gives me Child leg of that call. how can i fix that?

Comment: Twilio Accounts (Project/Sub-Accounts) are logical partitions. You cannot interact with a CallSID in one account from another account - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011132374-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Projects-and-Subaccounts. Can you keep everything in one account.

Comment: what will be the url when call connects? @Alan

Comment: I am not clear on your question, can you add more context around it?

Comment: On outgoing api calling there is a field [url](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-record-an-outbound-call&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#get-call-status-events-during-a-call).
What will be that url when call connects?

Comment: You define the URL (it can be a Twilio Studio Webhook URL, Twilio Function, or your own application server. It will be a source of Twilio Markup Language (TwiML) which is XML that tell Twilio what next steps to take - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml. Example of what TwiML looks like can be seen here - https://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml.